# PHP to prepend to file without loading it into memory?

Tags: php, memory, filesystems

I think the title pretty much says it all. I would like to prepend a String (a single line) to an existing TXT file. The existing file could potentially be very large so I'm trying to think of the most cost-efficient way of doing this.

I know the following will work:

```
$str = 'My new line';
$str .= file_get_contents('file.txt');
file_put_contents('file.txt', $str);
```

It seems overkill to have to load a huge file to just prepend a single line.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is limitation of filesystems. You have to rewrite the whole file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm inclined to use a PHP stream like `php://temp` which doesn't use the same memory as PHP, so isn't subject to the same limitations

```
$src = fopen('dummy.txt', 'r+');
$dest = fopen('php://temp', 'w');

fwrite($dest, 'My new line' . PHP_EOL);

stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);
rewind($dest);
rewind($src);
stream_copy_to_stream($dest, $src);

fclose($src);
fclose($dest);
```

Comment: This works great. Would you mind quickly explaining why this would be more efficient?

Comment: It's more efficient because it doesn't load all of dummy.txt into memory, but rather uses the [php://temp filestream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) instead

Answer (score 3):

```
$filename = 'text.txt';
$str = 'My new line';
$tmpname = 'tmp.txt';

$context = stream_context_create();
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r', 1, $context);
file_put_contents($tmpname, $str);
file_put_contents($tmpname, $fp, FILE_APPEND);
fclose($fp);
unlink($filename);
rename($tmpname, $filename);
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but I prefer Mark Baker's response as it doesn't use file_put_contents

Comment: Agree, his solution looks better, but time and memory usage are same. I have tested

Comment: Should be pretty similar in all regards because you're using a stream context, which makes it similar to the stream copy that I'm using; and the only real difference is that you're using a named file on disk while I'm using a named stream (php://temp) as the temporary file

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'My new line';
file_put_contents('file.txt', $str, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Is there an option to prepend? I tried FILE_PREPEND to no avail

Comment: sry, my fault. See my another solution